# how to check if object values are empty?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this structure:

```
const ob = {
name: ''
ob: {}
arr: []
}
```

I want to check if all values, are empty.
If I have only strings and arrays, the problem is trivial, but with an object my best solution is something like that,

```
const test = Object.values(ob).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const isPlainObject = typeof curr === 'object' && !Array.isArray(curr);

    if (isPlainObject) !Object.values(curr).length ? (acc = false) : null;
    else !curr.length ? (acc = false) : null;

    return acc;
  }, true);
```

I'm not satisfied with this, did anybody face similar problem and can help me with that?

Comment: do not use a ternary operator to set a variable.... bad practice. Seems like you should be using some or every, not reduce. What if there is a number?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are these the only *empty* values? Can the object have `null`, undefined or any other values that is considered as empty? `isPlainObject` will be true for `null`

Comment: @adiga thanks for that, I don't think it is possible to get null, or undef there, but I missed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the various types and then either the length or the count of (own enumerable) keys or the value.

```js
const
    isEmpty = object => Object.values(object).every(v => {
        if (Array.isArray(v)) return v.length === 0;
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') return Object.keys(v).length === 0;
        return v === '';
    }),
    ob = { name: '', ob: {}, arr: [] };

console.log(isEmpty(ob));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not so much better than your solution, C233. But I'll give it a shot ;)

```
const isEmpty = (val) => {
    if(!val) {
        return true;
    }
    if (typeof val === 'object') {
        return Object.values(val).length === 0;
    }
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
        return val.length === 0;
    }
    return false;
}

const hasEmptyProps = (obj) => Object.values.map(isEmpty).reduce((result, curr) => result && curr, true);
```